# Pandas to_sql doesn't create a file

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I'm trying to save my pandas dataframe as a SQL file

I followed the documentation and tried

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')
df.to_sql('filename.sql', engine, chunksize=1000)
```

However, when I check the directory with `os.listdir()`, the file is not there

Comment: I don't think thats the purpose of the `to_sql` method, at least I never used it that way. I always use it to export to a database.

Comment: so after it's exported to a database, would I use a sqlalchemy function to save that database to a file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first argument you pass to `to_sql` should be the name of the table in your database, not the name of the file. Take a look at the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html).

Also, if you want to create a sqlite file, you should create an engine with a [file](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/engines.html#sqlite) database, not in-memory:

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("sqlite:///mydb.db")  # relative path to db
df.to_sql("my_table", engine)
```

Now there should be a file named `mydb.db` in the same directory where you run your application/script, with a table `my_table` containing the data in `df`.

Comment: Say that I want to read the file into pandas later. Would I use `engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("sqlite:///mydb.db") `, then `with engine.connect() as conn, conn.begin():`, then `data = pd.read_sql_table('data', conn)` ?

Comment: No, you can pass the engine directly to `read_sql_table` as the `con` argument. The [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html#pandas.read_sql) say you can pass a SQLAlchemy _connectable_. So, this: `data = pd.read_sql_table('data', engine)`.